# Logging for Azure Function in python with SEQ

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I'm working on the Azure Function (durable function) that implements an HTTP trigger. All it does is waiting for an HTTP call from the backend that shares a link to a blob storage object (image) so it can be processed by a function. I need to implement a reliable logging solution using [SEQ](https://datalust.co/), that's being used for other projects in our company (mostly .NET).

Using some official documentation [from here](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/using-python) all I'm receiving in the SEQ console is a stream of unstructured events and it's hard to gain where and when the processing starts, how much time did it take, etc. It makes it impossible to troubleshoot.

With .NET projects we were using Serilog that allows you to write so-called enrichers and filters, so you can structurize the logs and the information that is really needed, including the call performance (e.g. elapsed time). I don't see anything even close to that available for Python 3. Can anyone suggest where do I start? What's the best approach to capture the events I'm looking for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, here's the answer:

- You need to install the lib called `seqlog` via `requirements.txt` for the purpose
- In the Python script where you plan to use logger import respective namespace, i.e. `import logging`
- Define SEQ configuration in a JSON file (something like this):
  [image]
- In the **init**.py load SEQ config:

  ```
    with open('./seq.config.json', 'r') as f:
        seq_config = json.load(f)
        f.close()
  ```
- Use `logging` object to stream the logs to SEQ:

`logging.info("[" + obj.status + "] >> Data has been processed!")`

- Enjoy the logs posted to the SEQ console

p.s. if you're debugging locally, set http://localhost+port in the `seq.config.json` instead of the remote console address

Hope this info will help someone.